# Image not loading in Android/IOS mobile browser

Tags: android, jquery, ios, ajax, mobile

I have a problem in my website. In my front page I created a loadmore prodjects functionality with isotope effect. Now when I test it on my PC using Firefox, Chrome & IE I can see all of the images. But when I test it on mobile all of the images won't display.

Here's a bit of my code for loading.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - $("footer").height()){
            page= page+1;

            $.ajax({

                url: 'index.php?route=common/home/loadMoreProject',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {'page':page },
                beforeSend: function(){ $('#loadmore').hide(); },
                complete: function(){ },
                error: function(){ },
                success: function(data){

                    $html= '';

                    if(data.project){

                        data.project.forEach(function(item) {

                            $html+= '<article class="col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-lg-2  isotopeItem '+item.code_identifier+'" style="min-width: 100px; min-height: 100px" >';
                                                $html+= '<div class="portfolio-item">';
                                                    $html+= '<img src="'+item.image+'" alt="" />';
                                                    $html+= '<div class="portfolio-desc align-center">';
                                                        $html+= '<div class="folio-info">';
                                                            $html+= '<a href="'+item.href+'" class="">';
                                                                $html+= '<h5>'+item.project_name+'</h5>';
                                                            $html+= '</a>';
                                                        $html+= '</div>';
                                                    $html+= '</div>';
                                                $html+= '</div>';
                                            $html+= '</article>';

                        });
                    }   
                    $container.isotope('insert', $($html));
                    $('#loadmore').show();

                }

            });


        }
});
```

I don't know if it is a code error. Can you help me with this?

Comment: are you loading it in a webview or mobile browser

Comment: I am viewing using the firefox mobile version in android but when I switch to desktop mode I can view all the images.